# Binary image resizing goes wrong

Tags: c#, image-processing, binary, memorystream

I try to resize a binary image to a smaller file if needed, however all images are getting more byte after resize, while size is getting smaller, so result is very ugly images...have no idea why its get bigger.

here is the code I use any help would be appreciated.

```
using (var srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemStream))
        {
            double height = srcImage.Height;
            double width = srcImage.Width;
            newWidth = (int)(srcImage.Width);
            double aspect = scale / width;
            newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(aspect * height);
            newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(aspect * width);
            using (var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight))
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                newImage.Save(ms, format);
                ms.Position = 0;

                _bytes = ms.ToArray();  //Returns a new byte array.
                newImage.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

**** update *****

```
            double height = srcImage.Height;
            double width = srcImage.Width;
            newWidth = (int)(srcImage.Width);
            double aspect = scale / width;
            newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(aspect * height);
            newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(aspect * width);

            Image scaledImage = ScaleDownTo(srcImage, newHeight, newWidth);
            newWidth = scaledImage.Width;
            newHeight = scaledImage.Height;
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            scaledImage.Save(ms, format);
            ms.Position = 0;
            _bytes = ms.ToArray();
            scaledImage.Dispose();
```

What I actually do is resize the image for example to a static max width, from any to 300px, so I calculate the current image width, take the aspect in double and resize this image to this size.

Any help on this is really appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a short function for scaling down images.

```
    public static Image ScaleDownTo(Image image, int height, int width) {
        if (image != null) {
            if (image.Width > width || image.Height > height) {
                float factor = Math.Max(((float)width) / image.Width, ((float)height) / image.Height);
                if (factor > 0) {
                    RectangleF imgRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, image.Width * factor, image.Height * factor);
                    imgRect.X = ((float)width - imgRect.Width) / 2f;
                    imgRect.Y = ((float)height - imgRect.Height) / 2f;
                    Bitmap cellImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
                    using (Graphics cellImageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(cellImage)) {
                        cellImageGraphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                        cellImageGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        cellImageGraphics.DrawImage(image, imgRect);
                    }
                    return cellImage;
                }
            }
            return image;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Just use it to get the new downscaled image.

Comment: Hi, tried your method, however still same issue, see update